# Limiting VM Search to specific cluster(s)?

Tags: vmware

I'm using C# and the VMware.Vim vsphere API's to do some searching, and for the most part it's working beautifully except that I can't figure out how to limit to a specific cluster in the datacenter.

For example:

```
NameValueCollection filter = new NameValueCollection();
filter.Add("Name", vmName2LookFor);

var ret = vimClient.FindEntityViews(typeof(VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine), null, filter, viewProperties);
var VMs = ret.Cast<VMware.Vim.VirtualMachine>().ToList();
```

I've seen suggestions for recursively crawling up the tree using the parent property until you hit the cluster level, but that seems like a really bad idea in terms of scaling as you get more results.

I've also seen references to using a TraversalSpec, but I can't really find any good documentation on it.

Can someone help me out here?

How would you grab all VM's in a cluster in a performant way and/or is there any documentation or can you give me some examples of using TraversalSpec?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just building a host=>cluster mapping for the entire datacenter and then checking the vm.Runtime.Host property against that mapping to ensure the vm was actually running under the specific cluster.

This ended up being effective, but below is the answer to the question I had about how to use a TraversalSpec.  Code is below, explanation underneath it.

```
public SelectionSpec[] buildTraversalFromDatacenterToVM() {
  // Recurse through all ResourcePools
  TraversalSpec rpToVm = new TraversalSpec() {
    Name = "rpToVm",
    Type = "ResourcePool",
    Path = "vm",
    Skip = false
  };
  // Recurse through all ResourcePools

  TraversalSpec rpToRp = new TraversalSpec() {
    Name = "rpToRp",
    Type = "ResourcePool",
    Path = "resourcePool",
    Skip = false,
    SelectSet = new[] {
      new SelectionSpec() { Name = "rpToRp" },
      new SelectionSpec() { Name = "rpToVm" }
    }
  };

  // Traversal through ResourcePool branch
  TraversalSpec crToRp = new TraversalSpec() {
    Name = "crToRp",
    Type = "ComputeResource",
    Path = "resourcePool",
    Skip = false,
    SelectSet = new[] {
      new SelectionSpec() { Name = "rpToRp" },
      new SelectionSpec() { Name = "rpToVm" },
    }
  };

  // Traversal through host branch
  TraversalSpec crToH = new TraversalSpec();
  crToH.Name = "crToH";
  crToH.Type = "ComputeResource";
  crToH.Path = "host";
  crToH.Skip = false;

  // Traversal through hostFolder branch
  TraversalSpec dcToHf = new TraversalSpec() {
    Name = "dcToHf",
    Type = "Datacenter",
    Path = "hostFolder",
    Skip = false,
    SelectSet = new[] { new SelectionSpec() { Name = "visitFolders" } }
  };

  // Traversal through vmFolder branch
  TraversalSpec dcToVmf = new TraversalSpec() {
    Name = "dcToVmf",
    Type = "Datacenter",
    Path = "vmFolder",
    Skip = false,
    SelectSet = new[] { new SelectionSpec() { Name = "visitFolders" } }
  };

  // Recurse through all Hosts
  TraversalSpec HToVm = new TraversalSpec() {
    Name = "HToVm",
    Type = "HostSystem",
    Path = "vm",
    Skip = false,
    SelectSet = new[] { new SelectionSpec() { Name = "visitFolders" } }
  };

  // Recurse through the folders
  TraversalSpec visitFolders = new TraversalSpec();
  visitFolders.Name = "visitFolders";
  visitFolders.Type = "Folder";
  visitFolders.Path = "childEntity";
  visitFolders.Skip = false;
  visitFolders.SelectSet = new[] {
    new SelectionSpec() { Name ="visitFolders" },
    new SelectionSpec() { Name ="dcToHf" },
    new SelectionSpec() { Name ="dcToVmf" },
    new SelectionSpec() { Name ="crToH" },
    new SelectionSpec() { Name ="crToRp" },
    new SelectionSpec() { Name ="HToVm" },
    new SelectionSpec() { Name ="rpToVm" },
    new SelectionSpec() { Name ="HToVm" },
  };

  return new SelectionSpec[] { visitFolders, dcToVmf, dcToHf, crToH, crToRp, rpToRp, HToVm, rpToVm };
}



public PropertyFilterSpec[] GetPropertyFilterSpec(ManagedObjectReference root,PropertySpec[] propSpecs) {
  if (typeinfo == null || typeinfo.Length == 0) {
    return null;
  }
  var selectionSpecs = buildTraversalFromDatacenterToVM();

  PropertyFilterSpec spec = new PropertyFilterSpec();
  spec.PropSet = propSpecs;
  spec.ObjectSet = new ObjectSpec[] {
    new ObjectSpec() {
      Obj = root,
      Skip = false,
      SelectSet = selectionSpecs
    }
  };

  return new PropertyFilterSpec[] { spec }
}
```

and here's how you would use the above functions

```
// NOTE:  setting All to true will return everything for the object, setting it to false
//        and filling out the PathSet will instead only return the properties specified
//        for performance.  For example, below for the HostSystem objects, everything
//        on the object will be null except for the name and the parent members
//
var propSpecs = new[] {
  new PropertySpec() {
     All = true,
     Type = "VirtualMachine"
  },
  new PropertySpec() {
     All = false,
     Type = "HostSystem",
     PathSet = new[]{ "name", "parent" }
  }
};


VimClient vimClient = new VMware.Vim.VimClientImpl();
var serviceContent = vimClient.Connect(hostname, VMware.Vim.CommunicationProtocol.Https, null);
var userSession = vimClient.Login(un, pwd);

var propertyCollector = new PropertyCollector(vimClient, serviceContent.PropertyCollector);

var specs = GetPropertyFilterSpec(serviceContent.RootFolder,propSpecs);
ObjectContent[] objContents = propertyCollectionr.RetrieveProperties(specs);
```

Now for the explanation.

Because the vmware infrastructure is basically a graph, the TraversalSpec describes how to climb that graph.  The names being assigned are user defined (anything you want), but are used to refer back to the specific spec for recursion.  In other words, it's much like a reference or a pointers.  For example, the VisitFolders spec refers back to itself with a selectionSpec.  This means it can support nested folders (multiple levels, not just 1).

Note that you can go further down than I did (into datastores, etc), but I didn't need to go that far.

Once you've described how to crawl through the graph, then you have to tell it what properties to return, which is what the propertySpec is for.

The PropertySpec has 2 uses.  1.  It acts as a quasi-filter, if you have no PropertySpec for the Entity then the vmware API's will return nothing for it.  If you do have a PropertySpec then it will return only the properties you ask it to.

So in the example above, It'll return ALL properties for VM's encountered in the traversal, and only the name and parent properties for all hosts encountered in the traversal.  Because I haven't specified any properties for folders, the request will traverse through folders but will not return anything back for them.

Here's documentation on what the vmware hierarchy looks like

https://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-50/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.vmware.wssdk.pg.doc_50%2FPG_Ch4_Introduction_Inventory.6.3.html

and documentation on the various Spec types

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.PropertySpec.html

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.SelectionSpec.html

https://www.vmware.com/support/developer/vc-sdk/visdk41pubs/ApiReference/vmodl.query.PropertyCollector.TraversalSpec.html